# How to make calls in Skype Preview using my SIM card?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, messaging, calls, skype

I was using Windows default messaging app, and somehow I decided to make my Skype Preview as default messaging app. Since I receive video calls.

At first I use the call from Skype (phone icon), I thought it was a normal call, taken with my SIM. But it's not, it demands me to "Add Skype Credit".

[image: skype]

How can I make a normal call from the Skype app using my SIM card?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Although the Skype Preview app is able to use legacy (voice+SMS) part of your cellular connection* to send SMS, it does not support cellular voice calls. All Skype calls (voice or video) are over the Internet, using either your WiFi or your cellular data connection. You need to continue using the Phone app to place calls using your usual minutes (or whatever) offered by your cell provider.

* It doesn't actually use the SIM per se, the SIM just identifies your account; your question is like asking how to turn on your bicycle using your car keys.

Comment: I don't know how to say that correctly. Sorry my bad. :)